Proposition 8 Corollary 1, Section 5.7 of Hungerford’s Algebra
Corollary 1.9. Let $E$ and $F$ each be extension fields of $K$ and let $u\in E$ and $v\in F$ be algebraic over $K$. Then $u$ and $v$ are roots of the same irreducible polynomial $f \in K[x]$ if and only if there is an isomorphism of fields $K(u) \cong K(v)$ which sends $u$ onto $v$ and is the identity on $K$.


If $K$ is a field of characteristic $p\neq 0$ and $x^p - x - a \in K[x]$, then $x^p - x - a$ is either irreducible or splits in $K[x]$.
Proof: We use the notation of Proposition 7.8. In view of the last paragraph of that proof it suffices to prove that if $\text{Aut}_KF \cong \text{Im}\theta = \Bbb{Z}_p$, then $x^p- x- a$ is irreducible. If $u$ and $v= u+i$ ($i\in \Bbb{Z}_p \subseteq K$) are roots of $x^p - x- a$, then there exists $\tau \in \text{Aut}_KF$ such that $\tau (u) = v$ and hence $\tau : K(u) \to K(v)$ (choose $\tau$ with $\theta (\tau ) = i$). Therefore, $u$ and $v$ are roots of the same irreducible polynomial in $K[x]$ (Corollary 1.9). Since $v$ was arbitrary this implies that $x^p - x - a$ is irreducible.

Question: I can’t fill details of last sentence “Since $v$ was arbitrary this implies that $x^p - x - a$ is irreducible”. The way it is written, I know this detail is not long or complicated. I just can’t seem to connect the dots. I have added relevant result above and my question is independent of proof of proposition 7.8.

This is a little confusingly written but the argument shows that $u, u+1, \dots u+p-1$ are all roots of the same irreducible polynomial. Since there are $p$ of them and $x^p - x - a$ has degree $p$, this irreducible polynomial must be $x^p - x - a$.
Alternatively you can phrase it as a proof by contradiction: suppose that $x^p - x - a$ was reducible. By calculating its formal derivative we know it has distinct roots. This means there must be two roots $u, v$ whose minimal polynomials are different (namely, two different irreducible factors of $x^p - x - a$). But we showed this does not happen. So $x^p - x - a$ is irreducible.
I think the second is closer to the intended line of reasoning but I think the first one is simpler and more direct.

Ahh! I think I got it. Following is my reasoning (sorry if I include too much details): Let $f$ be minimal polynomial of $u$ over $K$. Let $f_i$ be irreducible polynomial such that $u$ and $v_i=u+i$ are roots of $f_i$. Since minimal polynomial of $u$ is unique, we have $f=c_if_i$ for some $c_i\in K$. So $u,v_1,…,v_{p-1}$ are roots of $f$. We can write $$f=(x-u)(x-v_1)\cdots (x-v_{p-1})g=(x^p-x-a)g$$ where $g\in K[x]$. Since $f$ is irreducible and $x^p-x-a\in K[x]$, we must have $g=1$ and $f=x^p-x-a$ is irreducible.  Of course, your proof by contradiction is slick.

This is largely just spelling out what has already been said, but my guess for the argument that was intended in all its gory details was something like the following (it is also a bit more Galois theoretical in how it is articulated than Qiaochu's much more concise answer, which may appeal to some!):
If $K$ is a field of characteristic $\text{char}(K)=p>0$, the map $\alpha\colon K \to K$ given by $\alpha(x) = x^p-x$ is $\mathbb F_p$-linear, and so, for $a \in K$, the roots of $f(t) = t^p-t-a$ are just the solutions of  $\alpha(x)=a$, hence any two differ by a solution of the homogeneous equation $\alpha(x)=0$, that is, the solution space in $K$, if it is nonempty, is a translate of $\mathbb F_p$ (i.e. of the form $\beta + \mathbb F_p$, some $\beta \in K$) and so a . Since $\deg(f)=p=|\mathbb F_p|$ it follows that $f$ splits with $p$ distinct roots over $K$ if it has a root in $K$.
Now suppose that $f\in K[t]$ has no roots in $K$.  If $E$ is any field extension of $K$ in which $f$ has a root, $\gamma$ say, then $K(\gamma) = K(\gamma+j)$ for any $j \in \mathbb F_p$ is a splitting field for $f$. Let $g \in K[t]$ be the minimal polynomial of $\gamma$ over $K$. Since $f(\gamma)=0$ it follows that $g\mid f$ and hence $g$ over $K(\gamma)$ $g$ splits as a product of some subset $S$ of the roots of $f$. Since $f$ has no roots in $K$, $\deg(g)=|S|>1$, so that there is some $j \in \{1,2,\ldots,p-1\}$ such that $\gamma+j$ is also a root of $g$.
Now if $L:=K[t]/\langle g \rangle$ and we write $\bar{t}$ for the image of $t$ in $L$, then then there is a unique isomorphism $\theta\colon L \to K(\gamma)$ which is the identity on $K$ and maps $\bar{t}$ to $\gamma$. Similarly we have an isomorphism fixing $K$ given by $\theta_j(\bar{t}) = \gamma+j$ so that $\tau_j = \theta_j \circ \theta^{-1}$ gives an automorphism of $K(\gamma)$ mapping $\gamma$ to $\gamma +j$ which evidently preserves $g \in K[t]$, and thus must permute its roots.
But $\tau_j^k(\gamma) = \gamma+kj$, hence the orbit of $\gamma$ under the group of automorphisms generated by $\tau_j$ has size $p$ (and hence $\langle \tau_j \rangle$ has order $p$). Since $\tau_j$ permutes the roots of $g$, it follows that $g$ has order $p$, and hence $g = f$ so that $f$ is irreducible. It is also clear from this that if $E = K(\gamma)$ is a splitting field for $f\in K[t]$ then $\text{Aut}(E/K) \cong (\mathbb F_p,+)$, the cyclic group of order $p$.

Thank you for the answer with different point of view. I will read your answer.
